# Both observableArray itself and its inner value have push methods

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

```
var myObservableArray = ko.observableArray();   
myObservableArray.push('Some value');
```

or

```
myObservableArray().push('Some value');
```

In my opinion only the second one should work because `myObservableArray()` is an array while `myObservableArray` is a function. However, to my big surprise both of them work. Could someone explain to me how `push` method is applied to a function without any problem?

Comment: Look at what `myObservableArray()` returns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Knockout is open source, so you can find out by looking at the `observableArray` source code!

```
// Populate ko.observableArray.fn with read/write functions from native arrays
// Important: Do not add any additional functions here that may reasonably be used to *read* data from the array
// because we'll eval them without causing subscriptions, so ko.computed output could end up getting stale
ko.utils.arrayForEach(["pop", "push", "reverse", "shift", "sort", "splice", "unshift"], function(methodName) {
  ko.observableArray['fn'][methodName] = function() {
    // Use "peek" to avoid creating a subscription in any computed that we're executing in the context of
    // (for consistency with mutating regular observables)
    var underlyingArray = this.peek();
    this.valueWillMutate();
    this.cacheDiffForKnownOperation(underlyingArray, methodName, arguments);
    var methodCallResult = underlyingArray[methodName].apply(underlyingArray, arguments);
    this.valueHasMutated();
    // The native sort and reverse methods return a reference to the array, but it makes more sense to return the observable array instead.
    return methodCallResult === underlyingArray ? this : methodCallResult;
  };
});
```

https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/subscribables/observableArray.js#L101

As you can see, knockout exposes some of `Array.prototype`'s methods. It uses `apply` on the underlying array (`this.peek()`) to actually use the original methods (instead of mimicking them).

There is one important difference between calling `push` on the `observableArray` or on the underlying array:

*If you push to the underlying array, knockout will not automatically trigger an update*. (Notice the `this.valueHasMutated` in the extension code)

```js
var array1 = [1,2,3];
var array2 = [1,2,3];

var obsArr1 = ko.observableArray(array1);
var obsArr2 = ko.observableArray(array2);

obsArr1.subscribe(function() { console.log("Obs. Array 1 changed!"); });
obsArr2.subscribe(function() { console.log("Obs. Array 2 changed!"); });

obsArr1.push(4);
obsArr2().push(4);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```